# Gherkin - run Scenario Outline just once using every value

Tags: python, gherkin, python-behave

I'm using Python and behave.
Assume I have the following Gherkin script:

```
Scenario Outline: SO question

Given I navigate to page ABC
When I click "<button>"
Then It should appear in "<location>"

Examples: Buttons and locations

| button    | location  |
| button1   | location1 |
| button2   | location2 |
| button3   | location3 |
```

Running this scenario will go through all values from the beginning to the end, as expected, restarting the scenario each time.

My question is: is it possible to make the script go to the page ABC (execute the step GIVEN), and then make it execute the WHEN step in one go,without having it restart every time?

**This is what I want**:

```
-- Go to page ABC
---- Click button1 --> button1 goes to location1
---- Click button2 --> button2 goes to location2
---- Click button3 --> button3 goes to location3
```

This is **NOT** what I want:

```
-- Go to page ABC
---- Click button1 --> button1 goes to location1
-- Go to page ABC
---- Click button2 --> button2 goes to location2
-- Go to page ABC
---- Click button3 --> button3 goes to location3
```

Comment: well you are using a scenario outline they are meant to do that

Comment: and as an added plus, if you want to go to the page then click the button, how are you supposed to get back to the page with the buttons if you're now on location1? it just has to be done

Comment: You are still on page ABC after clicking a button. Each button moves to a different location on the page, but the URL stays the same.

Comment: then why don't you just use a normal scenario? if you're not having to go back and forth then you can just bundle it all in one instead of having the scenario outline make multiple scenarios...

Comment: Because I have like 30 buttons, which means one WHEN (or AND) per button, and then one THEN (or AND) per button. 60 lines of Gherkin script. Unfortunately each button needs to be mentioned by name in the script. Sorry, I only work here :D

Comment: That answer down there is all I got on this good luck though lol

Comment: Haha thanks. It's good, but I can't use it. The GIVEN, unfortunately, is included here under Background, and runs before each Scenario. Hmm I guess it's the 60 lines for me.... Actually, it's 78 :-(

Answer (score 0):

ok how about this: instead of navigating to "ABC" in the scenario, do that in another scenario before your button clicking scenario runs.

It's really risky because tests shouldn't depend on others but if that's what you want then that's what you get

```
Scenario: Navigate to ABC
Given I navigate to page ABC

Scenario Outline: Click some buttons
When I click "<button>"
Then It should appear in "<location>"

Examples: Buttons and locations

| button    | location  |
| button1   | location1 |
| button2   | location2 |
| button3   | location3 |
```

This way, you navigate to the page once then you loop for the buttons since you are no longer navigating to the page for each loop